# Appending into an empty JSON file in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-2.7

I already have a JSON file which I am parsing using Python 2.7 and I want to dump the parsed out data into another empty JSON file. I am using a for-loop to parse out the data from the old JSON file and at the same time within that loop I want to append to that new JSON file. My original JSON file is in the form of a JSON array. Note: The new JSON file will have the same keys as the old JSON file i.e I am just parsing out the data according to the if-condition and then inserting the whole index (that satisfies the condition) from the old JSON to the new JSON.
Old JSON = "output_log.json"
New JSON = "cumulative_output.json"

The new JSON file would be a list of indexes for eg something like this:

```
[{"name":".....", "commit":".....", "author":"...", "title":"...", "body":"..."},
{"name":".....", "commit":".....", "author":"...", "title":"...", "body":"..."},
.........
]
```

```
    with open("output_log.json", 'r') as f:
        json_ob = json.load(f)
      
        for index in range(len(json_ob)):
            if (bool(re.search(r"\s", json_ob[index]['name']))) is True and ('444' in json_ob[index]['title']) and ('https://robotics.com/projects/' in json_ob[index]['body']):
                with open('cumulative_output.json', 'a') as f:
                    entry = {'name': json_ob[index]['name'], 'commit': json_ob[index]['commit'], 'author': json_ob[index]['author'], 'title': json_ob[index]['title'], 'body': json_ob[index]['body']}
                    f.write(entry)
                    f.write(",")
```

Comment: You want a single JSON string in the output file? Process everything into a list and then json.dump that one list.

Comment: @tdelaney I have edited the question to show the example of the new JSON file. I just want to append as the data gets parsed to save time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading and writing a single JSON list object so there isn't a lot of opportunity to do things iteratively. Your current code fails because you can't write a python dictionary (`f.write(entry)`) without some sort of serialization. After reading the JSON list, you could filter it and write it again. You don't need the extra complication of indexing the list you read, just iterate it. And since you want to write the entire record, you don't need to create a new dictionary.

```
with open("output_log.json") as f:
    json_ob = json.load(f)

entries = []
for entry in json_ob:
    if (re.search(r"\s", entry["name"]) and ("444" in entry["title"])
            and (r"https://robotics.com/projects/" in entry["body"])):
        entries.append(entry)

with open("cumulative_output.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(entries)
```